# JQuery .click() triggers after the second click only

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use JQuery load() instead of javascript ajax. I have multiple of  `ids` generated for each `DIV` with php loop.

When creating a JQuery function like below I pass the generated ids of divs fine but, I will have to click twice on the button in-order the `.click()` event to trigger , I put a `window.alert()` inside the `.click()` function and it popups twice after the second click on the button, any idea how to do it the correct way?

**UPDATED**

```
function updateDivs(generatedID){
    $('#'+generatedID).click(function(){
        //do some .load() stuff
    });
}

<?php
 for($i=0 ; $i < 20 ; $i++){
   $gen = mt_rand(100,999);
?>
   <div id="<?=$gen;?>" onclick="updateDivs(<?=$gen;?>) > some content </div
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: You will probably need to provide more code than this. Do you have a bit of HTML to show?

Comment: @iMohammad Do you mean doubleclick?

Comment: I have updated my question and added the html/php part.

Comment: have you looked at how the jquery [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) works? what is your intention to use load instead ajax? (roughly there is no difference between those two)

Comment: Actually I meant the old Ajax not jquery Ajax. I've realized that jquery Ajax more powerful I've started using it. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the easiest way is to set a class for your divs and inside you can get the div id with event.target.id.

I think that your problem is that you need to have something like document.ready() or $(function() { });

```
<div id="div_id" class="mydiv"> some content </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".mydiv").click(function (event) {
            alert(event.target.id);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is binding a `doubleclick` event handler, which can be done this way:

```
$("<?=$gen;?>").on("dblclick", function (e) {
   // do some stuff here.
});
```